# Creating a Map<A,C> from Map<A,B> and Map<B,C>. Bonus points for Guava BiMap

Tags: java, dictionary

I have `Map<A, B> map1` and `Map<B, C> map2` and I need to produce a `Map<A, C>`. I'd also like a solution using guava's `BiMap` if that's possible.

Obviously assuming that there does exist a bijective map between sets A, B, and C. I want a *view*, that is I don't want to make any copies of the elements.

`map1` and `map2` are immutable.

```
public static <A, B, C> Map<A, C> merge(map1: Map<A, B>, maps2: Map<B, C>) {
    // best way to implement?
}
```

*Note: I would prefer an existing solution over creating my own `MergedMap<A, B, C> implements Map<A, C>` and implementing all the methods.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @pablochan I haven't "tried" anything so far. I could obviously make a `MergedMap<A,B,C> implements Map<A,C>` class and override all the methods but I was hoping there was a library that already exists or some method in guava/jdk that would help out.

Comment: If you're looking for an existing solution, you should mention that in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with [Maps.transformValues()](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Function-)

```
public static <A, B, C> Map<A, C> merge(Map<A, B> map1, Map<B, C> map2) {
    return Maps.transformValues(map1, map2::get);
}
```

From the documentation:

> Returns a view of a map where each value is transformed by a function. All other properties of the map, such as iteration order, are left intact.

> Changes in the underlying map are reflected in this view. Conversely, this view supports removal operations, and these are reflected in the underlying map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) with the stream of the entry set to transform the values.

```
public static <A, B, C> Map<A, C> merge(Map<A, B> map1, Map<B, C> map2) {
    return map1.entrySet().stream().collect(
       Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> map2.get(e.getValue())));   
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does copy the elements rather than creating a view, but otherwise it is a good solution.